# Add Custom Verb to ToolStrip designer without having to reimplement the ToolStripDesigner

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, design-time

I am developing a Custom ToolStrip to replace the TitleBar of a Form that I want to also double as a Menu Bar. What I am trying to do is add a Verb to the ToolStrips Verb Menu that will add Standard Menu Items such as File, Edit.

I can do this through a Custom ControlDesign however the Items add are not persisted in the InitializeComponent method of the Form. Also I don't think I want to use a custom ControlDesigner because I lose a lot of functionality that I will have to reemplement and the ToolStripDesigner is Internal so I can't inherit from that.

Is there any way I can add an option to the ToolStrips Verbs Menu similar to the Insert Standard Items without having to reemplement the ToolStripDesigner.

Thanks for any help
Danny

PS Sorry if this is a little rambling I haven't slept in 2 days.

Comment: You should not create a new control designer because you will lost current toolstrip designer functionalities like adding items using designer. Instead you should add the functionality which you need to the designer. On the other hand current toolstrip designer is internal and has dependencies to other internal classes and you can not inherit from it. A good option is finding the designer and manipulate designer at design-time.

Comment: Reza how would I go about manipulating the designer at design-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToolStripDesigner` is internal and has dependencies to other internal classes and you can not inherit from it. Also, you should not create a new control designer for `ToolStrip` because you will lose current designer functionalities like adding items using designer.

A really good *trick* is finding the designer and manipulate designer at design-time.

**How can I add a Custom Verb to ToolStrip designer without loosing designer functionalities?**

You can find the designer of your control at design-time and manipulate it. A good point is in `OnHandleCreated` method. You can get an instance of `IDesignerHost` from `Site` of the control and then get the designer. Then you can get action list collection of the control and add custom verb to it.

```
/*Add a reference to System.Design.dll*/

using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
public class MyCustomToolStrip : ToolStrip
{
    private IDesignerHost designerHost;
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if (this.DesignMode && Site != null)
        {
            designerHost = Site.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
            if (designerHost != null)
            {
                var designer = designerHost.GetDesigner(this);
                if (designer != null)
                {
                    var actionList = ((ControlDesigner)designer).ActionLists[0];
                    designer.Verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb("My Custom Verb", MyCustomVerb));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void MyCustomVerb(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("My Custom Verb added!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reza, I'll try this in the morning.

Comment: @dannyhut You are welcome :) Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Comment: @dannyhut Testing the validity of the answer is really easy. Do you have any problem in applying the solution? Let me know the result...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Reza, been working away from technology for 8 weeks. Managed to get evrything working well but the changes I make are not persisting in the designer. I can work around this however so all is good, it would be nice to be able to add to the designer file as native .NET Controls do though. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, hope you are doing well :) There is an elegant solution to persist changes that you make using the verb. You should notify the designer using `IComponentChangeService `, otherwise the changes will not save. If you asked a new question about that feel free to notify me,  I'll write working sample for the problem if you ask a question :)

Comment: Thanks Reza, again sorry for the late reply, I work in what is known as outback Australia. I will try and het the IComponentChangeService working for me without asking a question, but I may still need to. Will post here if a do. Thanks again